# Run and execute C program with single step in Emacs

Tags: c, emacs, zsh

*I'm new to Emacs* and I'd like execute C programs in a separate window with eshell (a window in top with C file and a window on bottom with eshell; switching back and forth with C-x o). Unfortunately, I have to write `gcc program.c -o program` and then `./program` in eshell.

In my .zshrc I have an alias

```
c () {
  gcc $1 && ./a.out
}
```

This means in the normal terminal I can just run `c program.c`, turning two steps into one. But of course, eshell doesn't read .zshrc. So how do I write an elisp file to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Are these C programs you are building? If so I have long set `make-command` in the header -- that allows you to do exactly what you do above: invoke compiler (with switches and options as needed) and then run it as Emacs will pass the whole string to `system()`.

Comment: Yeah. They are C programs.

Comment: Understood.  But from your own source code, ie you alter, compile, run?

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I have been doring for years. Add an Emacs header line as in the following example:

```
/* -*- mode: C++; compile-command: "gcc -s -O3 termcolor.c -o termcolor; ./termcolor" -*- */

#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
  printf("[0;34;41mHello world![m\n");
  printf("[5;34;41mHello world![m\n");
  printf("[1;5;34;41mHello world![m\n");

  return 0;
}
```

I make `C-x c` aliased to calling `M-x compile` (at least in C++ mode, which I set up here too even though it is technically a C file), so it invokes the `compile-command` specified here ... which includes the execution.

So almost immediately later I get

```
-*- mode: compilation; default-directory: "/tmp/" -*-
Compilation started at Sat Dec 24 13:22:23

gcc -s -O3 termcolor.c -o termcolor; ./termcolor
[0;34;41mHello world![m
[5;34;41mHello world![m
[1;5;34;41mHello world![m

Compilation finished at Sat Dec 24 13:22:24
```

in the *compilation* buffer.  Works well enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

Simply go into eshell and type `alias c 'gcc $1 && ./a.out'`